# Efficient method to extract Sentinel-2 band average per date per polygon using Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I have a folder with over 100 polygons, each polygon is relatively small (~5 ha). I would like to get the average per band, per date, per polygon. The final expected result should be a table. i.e., `pd.DataFrame` (or something I can convert to `pd.DataFrame`). This is the code I came up with:

```
def calculate_band_means_sentinel2(image):
    date = image.date().format("YYYY-MM-dd")
    mean_values = image.reduceRegion(reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(),geometry=polygon,scale=10)  
    return image.set({"date": date}).set(mean_values)


start_date,end_date = '2021-01-01','2024-01-01'
desired_keys = ['date','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B11','B12']
filtered_dicts = []

for poly_path in poly_paths: #poly path is the full path to the geojson file
    with open(poly_path) as f:
        gj = geojson.load(f)
    try:
        geometry = gj['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates']
    except:
        geometry = gj['coordinates']

    polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon(geometry[0])
    collection = (ee.ImageCollection( "COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED").filterBounds(polygon).filterDate(start_date,end_date))
    result_collection = collection.map(calculate_band_means_sentinel2)
    raw_data = result_collection.getInfo()
    
    for original_dict in raw_data['features']:
        try:
            filtered_dict = {key: original_dict['properties'][key] for key in desired_keys if key in original_dict['properties']}
            filtered_dicts.append(filtered_dict) 
        except:
            pass
```

This works for me and the result (`pd.DataFrame(filtered_dicts)`) is as desired:

```
    date         B2      B3      B4      B5      B6      B7      B8      B11    B12
0   2021-01-03  0.026   0.045   0.024   0.066   0.272   0.339   0.315   0.145   0.068
1   2021-01-08  0.036   0.056   0.030   0.078   0.321   0.420   0.388   0.177   0.088
2   2021-01-13  0.210   0.213   0.186   0.223   0.365   0.422   0.397   0.239   0.164
3   2021-01-18  0.572   0.571   0.559   0.530   0.585   0.639   0.634   0.166   0.161
4   2021-01-23  0.021   0.044   0.019   0.068   0.423   0.568   0.543   0.220   0.092
```

What's bothering me is the `.getInfo()` that I constantly use for each loop. Is there a more efficient method to achieve it?